# UpdateView doesnt save the avatar field?

Tags: django

I have abstract User with avatar field.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)
```

And views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'bio', 'location', 'birth_date', 'avatar', )
    template_name = 'my_account.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('my_account')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

I can see fields and can save all of it except avatar .
What to do?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your template.

Comment: YES, THX so MUCH

Answer (score 0):

Forget to add enctype="multipart/form-data" in template to form.